# background image button glitch using css class

Tags: css, asp.net, button

I have a link button that has a background image which is glitching when on display, is not centered but when hover becomes normal. both pictures are on the same size.

On display only. Image [Here](http://prntscr.com/5yu2sw)

When hovered. Image [Here](http://prntscr.com/5yu30u)

Before I was only using BtnSave class but I want to separate the width height and display styles.

CODE:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" CssClass="BtnIcon Save" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

CSS:

```
.BtnIcon {
    width: 50px; height: 50px; display: block;
}
.Save
{
    background-image: url('../Images/Buttons/save.png');
}
.Save:hover {
    background: url('../Images/Buttons/savehover.png');
}
```

OLD CODE:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" CssClass="BtnSave" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

OLD CSS:

```
.Save
{
    width: 50px; height: 50px; display: block;
    background-image: url('../Images/Buttons/save.png');
}
.Save:hover {
    width: 50px; height: 50px; display: block;
    background: url('../Images/Buttons/savehover.png');
}
```

the Old code was working fine but I think it is not good declaring the same style over and over again... Or that should it be?

I need to make sure that the blue icon doesn't crop out on the left and make it center just like the hovered one, But using the new code but can't seem to center it using that one.

Comment: it shouldnt cause that. please insert a working snippet into your question, or recreate the issue in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can see it.

Comment: How can I recreate a asp program on fiddle? cant seem to work using the asp code

Comment: it doesnt. you need to use the post-rendered html that you get after you run the website

Comment: no worries i think i found the error causing it.

Comment: awesome, please post it as an answer and accept it. it might help oter developers in the future who experience similar issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite existing position codes.

CSS:

```
.Save {
    background-position: center center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you give background image to some u need to declare the url path, no-repeat, the background's x-position , the background's y-position, and even given the button a proper width and height it will work

eg. button {

background: url(../path) no-repeat center 5px;

width:100px;//how much space button should occupy horizontal

height:50px;//how much space button should occupy vertical

}

similarly for hover